# Textfield - Make sure the user fill in at least one field

Tags: ios7, uitextfield

On the Sign Up in my app I want to make sure that the user fill in one field. **It should not matter which field for the user though.** That's the problem I'm having. The closet I get is to force the user to fill in one specific textfield like the code below. And that's not the best UX i guess :) Anyone who know what to do?

```
 self.saveButton.delegate = self;


- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([self.RandomTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        self.saveButton.enabled = NO;
    } else {
        self.saveButton.enabled = YES;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)SignUPBtn:(UIButton *)sender {

   if(txtName.text.length==0 && txtEmail.text.length==0 && txtPass.text.length==0)
   {
         [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please Fill Atleast One Field" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];

   }
   else
   {
      //Write Your Code here. this else called only if anyone of three textfield is filled up.

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the click event of the sign_up button

```
- (IBAction)SignUPBtn:(UIButton *)sender {
      if([textfeld_Email.text length]>0)
    {
        //sign up
    }
    else
    {
        if([textfeld_Pswd.text length]>0)
        {
         //sing up   
        }

        else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please enter your email and pass" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

        }
    }  


}
```

Comment: Thanks man. But I only want the user to fill 1 out of 3 fields though to be able to save. The most IMPORTANT is that the user can chose witch fields to fill in them self. Do you understand what I'm looking for?

Comment: you have three textfeild  so when user click and write in the any textfield [textfeld.text length] you will find that which textfeild is fill or not

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I do that in the best way. I don't really understand..